# How do I pass this Generic type an argument in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, use-state

I'm having trouble properly forming an argument to a type.

Here is my interface

```
export interface IAssetGetManyResponseDto<T> {
  items: T[];
  totalCount: number;
}
```

In my app, I would like to pass an argument to a useState hook, and with useState and useEffect, fetch some data that has a response of the type `IAssetGetManyResponseDto`.

Here's the larger context of how I am trying to pass the type an argument, and what I'm trying to do

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getAllAssets } from '../api/api';

import { NewAssetTable } from "../components/NewAssetTable"
import { IAssetGetManyResponseDto } from '../types/types';


export const AssetManagementTable = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState<IAssetGetManyResponseDto>()

  const getAssets = async () => {
    const assets = await getAllAssets();
    console.log(data)
    console.log(assets)
    setData(assets)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getAssets()
  }, []);

  return (

    <div>
      <NewAssetTable items={data.items} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The error:

```
Generic type 'IAssetGetManyResponseDto<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).  TS2314

     8 | export const AssetManagementTable = () => {
     9 | 
  > 10 |   const [data, setData] = useState<IAssetGetManyResponseDto>()
       |                                    ^
    11 | 
    12 |   const getAssets = async () => {
    13 |     const assets = await getAllAssets();
```

What should the argument look like?  And how would I access the response once I've formulated it correctly?

At the risk of adding more code than necessary and disappearing into SO oblivion, I'll end there!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hint the generic with a type:

```
// Define your data type
type MyDataType = number;

const [data, setData] = useState<IAssetGetManyResponseDto<MyDataType>>()
```

Comment: Followup that I hope is helpful to the world - if I have the response type `export interface IAssetResponseDto {
  id: string | null;
  name: string | null;
  type: string | null;
  url: string | null;
  // metadata: IMetadataObj| null;
  tags: Array<string> | null;
  thumbnailImageURL: string | null;
  createdAt: number | null;
  updatedAt: number | null;
}` and I hint the generic like this `useState<IAssetGetManyResponseDto<IAssetResponseDto>>()` then what shape am I actually telling useState to use?  Can't figure out how to make arguments to access the `items []` array of objects

Comment: thanks very much!  Btw if you're hunting another green checkmark, you might be able to easily be my hero in the larger question, posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69213626/how-to-correctly-set-react-usestate-using-generics