# How to correctly set react useState using generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, use-effect, use-state

Core question - where am I messing up my useState

```
  const [data, setData] = useState<IAssetGetManyResponseDto<IAssetResponseDto>>();
```

so that the `data` object I'm sending down as props is `undefined`?

My (functioning) api call looks like this

```
export const getAllAssets = async (
 
): Promise<IAssetGetManyResponseDto<IAssetResponseDto>> => {
  console.log("get all assets ran in api.ts!")
  const response = await amsApiClient.get(ASSET_ENDPOINT(),
  {
    params: {
      limit: 1000
    }
  }
  );
  console.log("logging response data "+JSON.stringify(response.data))
  return response.data;
};
```

Here are the types being used:

```
export interface IAssetGetManyResponseDto<T> {
  items: T[];
  totalCount: number;
}

export interface IAssetResponseDto {
  id: string | null;
  name: string | null;
  type: string | null;
  url: string | null;
  // metadata: IMetadataObj| null;
  tags: Array<string> | null;
  thumbnailImageURL: string | null;
  createdAt: number | null;
  updatedAt: number | null;
}
```

And here is the component that makes the call, to show context

```
export const AssetManagementTable = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState<IAssetGetManyResponseDto<IAssetResponseDto>>();

  const getAssets = async () => {

    console.log("getAssets ran!")

    const assets = await getAllAssets();
    console.log("logging data from asset managment table " + data)
    console.log("logging assets from asset managment table " + assets)
    setData(assets)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getAssets()
  }, []);

  return (

    <div>
      <NewAssetTable items={data} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Elsewhere in my app, when I pass props down and refer to `props.items.map((item: any). => {...` I'm getting `undefined`.

More specifically, `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

Am I messing up the argument to useState by improperly specifying types?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ba2bb0f/types/react/index.d.ts#L916) for `React.useState` are little unsafe. They don't augment return type with `undefined` for variant with no arguments.

So, if you told that state will always contain `IAssetGetManyResponseDto<IAssetResponseDto>`, TS compiler believes it.

Hover on `data` to see it has `IAssetGetManyResponseDto<IAssetResponseDto>` while it should be `IAssetGetManyResponseDto<IAssetResponseDto> | undefined`.

Workaround:

- `useState<IAssetGetManyResponseDto<IAssetResponseDto> | undefined>()`
- `useState<IAssetGetManyResponseDto<IAssetResponseDto>>(someFunctionalMockOfYourData)`

Comment: Thanks @Zbigniew!  I've been trying to do the second option you mentioned, `useState<IAssetGetManyResponseDto<IAssetResponseDto>>(someFunctionalMockOfYourData)` .  I just can't figure out how to mock the data to pass the useState! 
Added the type interfaces to the question if that helps figuring out how to functionally mock the data.

Comment: Classic "loading" protblem. You have basically 3 choiceschoices 1) Don't show `NewAssetTable`, and show some "loading..." placeholder. 2) Ensure `NewAssetTable` works with `data=undefined` 3) Prepare "empty mock" ... It's your call now, when you have proper typings :)

Comment: Thanks! But what would the empty mock look like?  And how would I pass it to useState?

Comment: `const [data, setData] = useState<IAssetGetManyResponseDto<IAssetResponseDto>>({
    items: [], totalCount: number
  });`
 ?

Comment: Yep, looks like `{items: [], totalCount: 0}` can work for your case. However, I _don't_ know your app. You must decide what to show while data is still not available.